# Computation of an étale cohomology group on the projective line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

I have the following problem: Let $U_{0}$ be a a smooth geometrically irreducible affine curve over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, and let  $\mathcal{E}_{0}$ be a constructible étale  sheaf of $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-vector spaces on $U_{0}$. By $\mathbb{F}$ we denote an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ and by $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ we denote the projective space over $\mathbb{P}^{1}$. By $U$ we denote the base change of $U_{0}$ to $\mathbb{F}$ and by $\mathcal{E}$ we denote the inverse image of $\mathcal{E}_{0}$ on $U$. Further, we denote by $j$ the inclusion of $U$ into $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ and by $i$ we denote the inclusion of its complements to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$. 
Then 
$$H^{1}_{ét}(\mathbb{P}^{1}, i_{*}i^{*}j_{*}\mathcal{E})=0.$$ This is what i don't understand. I am interested in this, because i want to deduce from the cohomology sequence of
$$   0\rightarrow j_{!}j^{*}j_{*}\mathcal{E}\rightarrow j_{*}\mathcal{E}\rightarrow i_{*}i^{*}j_{*}\mathcal{E}\rightarrow 0$$ 
that
 $$H_{c}^{1}(U,\mathcal{E})\twoheadrightarrow H_{ét}^{1}(\mathbb{P}^{1}, j_{*}\mathcal{E}).$$ 
I hope somebody can help me with this problem! Many thanks in advance

Comment: Milne uses the assertion is his Lectures on ÉtaleCohomology http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LEC.pdf  on page 186. And Pierre Deligne uses the statement in Weil I  http://archive.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1974__43__273_0.pdf on page   286.

Comment: I believe there are a couple of typos and some non written hypotheses in your definitions. Here is what I think it should be, please correct me if I'm wrong. $U_0\subset\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_q}$ is an open subscheme which is the complement of a finite number of closed point, and $U$ is the base change to $\mathbb{F}$ (and not $\mathbb{P}^1$). So $U$ is also the complement in $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}}$ of $Z$, a finite number of points.

Now $Z$ is just a finite number of points (over an algebraically closed field), so has a vanishing $H^1$...

Comment: (Use $H^1_{ét}(\mathbb{P}^1,i_*i^j_*\mathcal{E})=H^1_{ét}(Z,i ^*j_*\mathcal{E})$)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Of course, $U$ should be the base change to $\mathbb{F}$. That was a typo and i corrected it. What you said about $U$ being the complement  of a finite number of closed point isn't part of the assertion in Milne. However, it is true in my setting. So i think Milne probably forgot to make this assumption and that probably confused me. Thank you very much !

Comment: In Milne, $U$ is an open subset of a complete curve $X$. The complement of $U$ in $X$ is also a finite number of points.